# Manejo de ramas en git al descargar repositorio remoto

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, ramas-git

En la primera vez que descargo el repositorio de git al dar doble click sobre una rama en remotes/origin, ej: con la rama  sipTja_Desarrollo esta pasa de remotes/origin a  sipTja y ahi ya se empieza a trabjar.   Como se haria este proceso por consola de comandos.    y que quiere decir que al descargarse por primera vez solo se vea en sipTja la rama "master"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo muy bien que es llo que buscas, podrías explicarte mejor?
Intentas descargar una rama de origin o subir una o hacer un merge a una rama de origin?

Comment: que significa los 2 apartados sipTja y remotes origin, porque la primera vez que descargo el repositorio y voy consola y ejecuto el comando:               $git branch
 master   (solo veo master)

Comment: Al dar doble click sobre una rama en el apartado remotes/origin  esta si pasa a siptTja, como se llama esa accion. y como se haria desde consola usando git

Comment: en el primer comentario quize decir ejecutar el comando "$git branch", solo que  no supe como poner saltos de linea

Comment: Por lo que yo entinedo cuando le diste doble click a una rama de remotes/origin esta se ha descargado a to local, esto en comandos sería: git checkout -b sipTja_Desarrollo origin/sipTja_Desarrollo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La primera lista de los repositorios locales la muestras con:

```
git branch
```

La segunda lista de los repositorios remotos con:

```
git branch -r
```

Cuando haces doble click en un repositorio (p.e. sipTja_Desarrollo), ejecutas basicamente dos comandos:

```
git checkout sipTja_Desarrollo
git pull
```

En algunos casos los IDE (Visual Studio u otros), a veces ejecutan otros comandos o flags adicionales de comprobación, pero con lo que puse deberías poder hacer lo mismo desde consola.

> que quiere decir que al descargarse por primera vez solo se vea en sipTja la rama "master"

Por defecto cuando clonas un repositorio la rama `master` es la única disponible en tu ambiente local (la que se supone es el código de producción), conforme lo necesites puedes descargarte branches del repositorio remoto o crear nuevos branches y publicarlos.

Comment: Muchas gracias  ya me despejaste un poco el panorama, mira en este primer estado "la rama master es la única disponible en tu ambiente local", y las otras ramas están en remotes/origin, como agregas a repositorios locales lo que están en remotos desde consola.

Comment: si con lo ultimo que me explicas, si me refiero a eso "que quiere decir que al descargarse por primera vez solo se vea en sipTja la rama "master" "

Comment: Para bajar los branches remotos al local con los últimos comandos que puse: `git checkout repositorio` y `git pull` debería bastar

Comment: Cuando clonas un repositorio, GIT no sabe cuál (o cuáles) branches necesitas por lo que siempre te baja sólo el `master`, por ejemplo, ahora estoy en un proyecto privado donde el repositorio tiene 17 branches pero yo sólo trabajo en 2 de ellos, los otros 15 sólo ocuparían espacio en disco.